# Sorting by date or string

Tags: javascript, sorting

Through the API I could receive two types of value i.e number or date of value a certain key. Like:

```
var data = [{ title: 'A', value: '10' }, { title: 'B', value: '9' }, { title: 'C', value: '20' }, { title: 'D', value: '14' }];
```

or

```
var data = [{ title: 'A', value: 'November 11, 2019' }, { title: 'B', value: 'January 12, 2019' }, { title: 'C', value: 'October 28, 2019' }, { title: 'D', value: 'March 13, 2018' }]
```

I was using a generic sorting function to sort the value. I need help to adjust it for date type value.

Code in use:

```
export function compareValues(key, order = 'ascending') {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return 0;
    }
    let comparison = 0;

    const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
      a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
    const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
      b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];


    if (varA > varB) {
      comparison = 1;
    } else if (varA < varB) {
      comparison = -1;
    }
    return (
      (order == 'descending') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: Assuming the two data types are an int and a date in month-first format, you could simply use `parseInt` and check for `NaN`. It's not the prettiest thing in the world, but ideally you wouldn't have two data types coming down in the same property to begin with.

Comment: what is the sort order of dates?

Comment: @DBS Thank you! I used the method you suggested. I will post the answer and please help me clean it up a bit :D

Comment: @NinaScholz it can be both asc or desc.

Answer (score 0):

So, like DBS from comment section suggested, I checked if the data is number or not and if it is a string, I checked if it is a valid date or not. Fortunately, I only receive date or number. So, I updated my code to be:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export function compareValues(key, order = 'ascending') {
  return function (a, b) {
    if (!a.hasOwnProperty(key) || !b.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return 0;
    }
    let comparison = 0;

    if (isNaN(a[key]) && isNaN(b[key])) {
      var aDate = moment(a[key]);
      var bDate = moment(b[key]);

      if (aDate.isValid() && bDate.isValid()) {

        var difference = aDate.diff(bDate);
        if (difference > 1) {
          comparison = 1;
        } else {
          comparison = -1;
        }
      }
    }


    const varA = (typeof a[key] === 'string') ?
      a[key].toUpperCase() : a[key];
    const varB = (typeof b[key] === 'string') ?
      b[key].toUpperCase() : b[key];

    if (comparison === 0) {
      if (varA > varB) {
        comparison = 1;
      } else if (varA < varB) {
        comparison = -1;
      }
    }
    return (
      (order == 'descending') ? (comparison * -1) : comparison
    );
  };
}
```